# Create XAMARIN DROID Project

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin example solution. Unfortunately, the Droid project doesn't present the solution.

How can I create the Droid project for launching the application on the android emulator?

[image: Xamarin solution]

Comment: Your `Xamarin.Android` project is called **"Location"**

Comment: It doesn't like Xamarin.forms. There is only Xamarin.Android project, if you select `Android` not `Cross-Platform` when you create the prooject. So you must name your project as Location when you create it. At last, this is a android project named Location, just create and start a simulator, run your project on it .